# How to show posts rank based on custom field value

Tags: posts, custom-field, query, title

I have total 100 posts, 10 posts in each page on homepage with paginatin. Here is my code

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    // Add additional args here
];
$post_ids = get_posts( $args );

if ( $post_ids ) {
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args_2 = [
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_in' => $post_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_key'          => 'custom_field',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', //or 'meta_value_num'
        'order'             => 'DESC',
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $args_2 );
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();?>
//loop here
<?php }
        next_posts_link( 'Next Posts', $q->max_num_pages );
        previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' );
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I want to show Rank # before title based on custom field value.

Example:

> Rank # Post Title

Comment: How do you define rank?

Comment: I define it based on custom field value.

Comment: OK, great, I'm posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated, rank is defined by a value in a custom field, so you would just need to get the value from the custom field and display it.

You can try the following inside your loop

```
global $post;

// Just make sure the custom field name is correct
$rank = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field', true ); 

// Display the title and rank
echo 'Rank ' . $rank . ' ' . get_the_title();
```

### EDIT

Your ordering is incorrect in your code. Loop one should be sorted accoring to your custum field value. In loop 2, you would want to sort by the order of the ids passed to `post_in`

Your complete code should look like the following

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'meta_key'       => 'custom_field',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', //or 'meta_value_num'
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    // Add additional args here
];
$post_ids = get_posts( $args );

if ( $post_ids ) {
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args_2 = [
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby'   => 'post__in',
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $args_2 );
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        global $post;

        // Just make sure the custom field name is correct
        $rank = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field', true ); 

        // Display the title and rank
        echo 'Rank ' . $rank . ' ' . get_the_title();

        // Rest of your loop here
    }
        next_posts_link( 'Next Posts', $q->max_num_pages );
        previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' );
        wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

### EDIT 2

To display the rank as number in query, you can do the following; (***NOTE:*** This is untested)

```
function get_post_rank( $query = '' ) 
{
      global $wp_query;

    // If $query is empty or not an instanceof WP_Query, use $wp_query
    if ( !$query || !$query instanceof WP_Query) 
        $query = $wp_query;

    // Set up our variables for calculations
    $current_post = ( $query->current_post + 1 );
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $ppp = $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];

    // If this is the first page, simple return the current post number
    if ( $paged == 1 )
        return $current_post;

    // If current page is not 1, calculate our post number
    return ( $paged * $ppp ) - ( $ppp - $current_post );
}
```

Then inside the loop, do the following:

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'meta_key'       => 'custom_field',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', //or 'meta_value_num'
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    // Add additional args here
];
$post_ids = get_posts( $args );

if ( $post_ids ) {
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args_2 = [
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby'   => 'post__in',
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $args_2 );
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        $rank = get_post_rank( $q ); 

        // Display the title and rank
        echo 'Rank ' . $rank . ' ' . get_the_title();

        // Rest of your loop here
    }
        next_posts_link( 'Next Posts', $q->max_num_pages );
        previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' );
        wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Pieter Goosen I add random numbers in million and billions using custom field and i want to show rank based on the highest number.

Comment: Not getting you. Does my code not display. The code in your question should do that ordering already

Comment: See my update, this should work now

Comment: It simply show the numbers entered in custom fields. I want to show rank based on numbered entered in custom field.
Post one - custom field value = 400
Post two - custom field value = 500
Post three - custom field value = 100
now rank should be like below
Rank#1 Post two
Rank #2 Post one
Rank #3 Post three and so on. hope I am not confusing.

Comment: So post 1 should be #1 and the last post #100

Comment: With my update, the sorting should be correct, post one has the highest value and post 100 the lowest. Please confirm

Comment: Post Two should be highest as it has value 500

Comment: And If i add another post say Post four and custom field value 600 It should become highest rank means Rank #1

Comment: It shows custom field value instead of showing rank. Like Rank #500, Rank #600 and so on

Comment: Yes, that I know, but we must sort the ordering out. If the ordering is this haywire, it is really an issue displaying the rank number

Comment: Ordering is perfect.

Comment: Please see my update in **EDIT 2**. I hope this is what you need. I'm off to bed now, it is really late. If there is any issue, I will try to sort it out tommorow

Comment: Pieter, Thank you so much. It works as i wanted, now question is how to show the same rank in single post?

Comment: You should accept this answer then and start a new question with this new requirement. We do have a one question per post policy :-).

Comment: I just posted another question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194776/post-rank-on-single-post-page-based-on-custom-field