# Pagination not working for category posts

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I am using [WP-PageNavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) pagination and because of certain reasons I have "Blog pages show at most" set to 100 and I can't reduce it.

I have a total of 30 posts in a category. I want to display 10 posts on each page but it doesn't display pagination; it displays only if a category has more then 100 posts. Code is below:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var( 'cat' ); 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$found_posts = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 10,
    'cat'                 => $cat_id,
    'meta_key'            => "custom_key",  
    'meta_value'          => '',
    'meta_compare'        => '!=',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num', // or 'meta_value_num'
    'order'               => "DESC",
    'paged'               => $paged
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $found_posts );
while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
    global $post;

    // Loop Here

endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) { 
    wp_pagenavi(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not run custom queries in place of the main query on the home page and any type of archive page. This will always cause an issue. If you need to alter the main query, use `pre_get_posts` to do so.

To solve this issue, you need remove your code from your category page and go back to the default loop. You should only have the following in your category page

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
        // YOUR MARKUP AND TEMPLATE TAGS
     }
}
```

This will led that you will see all category posts on the category post ordered by post date. As I said, you now need to use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query on category pages to set your custom ordering and pagination

You need to add the following in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only target the front end queries
         && $q->is_main_query() // Targets the main query only
         && $q->is_category() // Only target category pages
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        $q->set( 'meta_key', 'custom_key' );
        $q->set( 'meta_value', '' );
        $q->set( 'meta_compare', '!=' );
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $q->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', 1 );
    }
});
```

You should no see 10 posts per page ordered by `meta_value_num` from the custom field `custom_key` sorted highest to lowest on your category pages

Comment: Pieter, It works great but as per your previous answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194628/how-to-show-posts-rank-based-on-custom-field-value/194730#194730. I have added rank function before loop It works perfect in main page but rank is not showing up in category page.

Comment: Just do `$rank = get_post_rank( $wp_query );`

Comment: I have updated the post rank function. Inside the main query you can now just do `$rank = get_post_rank();`. For custom queries you still need to do `$rank = get_post_rank( $q );`. Check out the updated version [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/194730/31545). PS!!! Don't forget to accept my answer if it worked ;-)

Comment: Search isn't working pagination.

Comment: Please rephrase. If I read this correctly, then the pagination on the search page is not working, if so, this has nothing to do with this issue

Comment: Pieter, I understand. I just created another issue
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195167/pagination-not-working-search-posts

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "selected answer", this might be needed:

```
$q->set( 'post_type', get_post_types() );
```