# Pagination not working Search posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    global $post;
    //loop here
  }
  if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
}
```

I have the following code in function as per the previous answer [Pagination not working for category posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195053/pagination-not-working-category-posts/195060)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only target the front end queries
         && $q->is_main_query() // Targets the main query only
         && $q->is_category() // Only target category pages
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        $q->set( 'meta_key', 'custom_key' );
        $q->set( 'meta_value', '' );
        $q->set( 'meta_compare', '!=' );
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $q->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', 1 );
    }
});
```

Comment: That `pre_get_posts` action only works for category pages. If you need to include the search page, change `&& $q->is_category()` to `&& ( $q->is_category() || $q->is_search() )`. But still, I can't see how this is related :-)

Comment: 'not working' - what is happening? what is not happening? what is wrong?

Comment: Using above code Category, Search, Tags pagination is fine but ranking is not working.